# Shouldn't tasksel be installed by default?

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, server

It just isn't there on the base install of a virtual host I am evaluating from an ISP.

Not in path:

```
root@vpstest2:~# tasksel       
-bash: tasksel: command not found
```

Config files not there:

```
root@vpstest2:~# ls /usr/share/tas*
ls: cannot access /usr/share/tas*: No such file or directory
```

It's just .... gone!

```
root@vpstest2:~# whereis tasksel
tasksel:
```

I'm a little concerned that the install is broken. Running locate spews this out:

```
locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [server manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.1-server-amd64.list) it is installed by default. It must have been removed at some point in your install perhaps? To reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

The second error is probably because you haven't run updatedb yet:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Answer (score 0):

First run like root:

```
updatebd
```

this will index your files, then make sure that you have already installed tasksel:

```
aptitude search tasksel
```

if you dont, run:

```
apt-get install tasksel
```

hope this help!!!

cheers!!!

Comment: You might change "run like root" to just `sudo`, as `sudo updatedb` .   You've also typed "updatebd" instead of "updatedb" .   Also bear in mind that you are duplicating most of Jorge's answer.   You might consider emphasizing the use of `aptitude search`, or even just adding that as a comment to Jorge's answer.